# Как обновлять БД при изменении DataGrid (WPF) используя SqlConnection

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server

Имеется программа на C# WPF и БД на 3 связанных таблицы в MS SQL Server. Для привязки данных используется класс SqlConnection и т.д. (ниже будут код и скриншоты). Вывод данных работает без проблем:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["productsdb"].ConnectionString);
    private DataTable dt;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DbConnection("products");
    }

    private void DbConnection(string table)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM {table} ORDER BY id", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dt = new DataTable(table);
            da.Fill(dt);

            prodGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            // tableName.Content = table[0].ToString().ToUpper() + table.Substring(1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Исключение: ", ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Результат работы метода для всех таблиц:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Требуемая задача заключается в корректном добавлении, редактировании и удалении строк в таблице непосредственно через DataGrid, но я никак не могу найти рабочее решение. Единственное, что есть, это вот такой кусок кода:

```
con.Open();
            string table = tableName.Content.ToString().ToLower();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM {table} ORDER BY id", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Update(dt);

            prodGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

При попытке добавить значение в колонку и сохранить изменение, выскакивает исключение:
"Для элемента Update требуется действительный InsertCommand(UpdateCommand, DeleteCommand) при передаче коллекции DataRow с новыми строками."

Comment: И еще один с Ado.net, чтож вас всех туда тянет то) По поводу вопроса: 1. Отделите данные от контролов, сделайте нормальные классы, приведите все к этому классу. У вас должно быть так, чтоб без UI ваша программа работала, чтоб не было в коде всяких `controlName.Text = ""`. WPF это привязки, если вы ими не пользуетесь, то зачем вам WPF? 2. Когда вы сделаете нормальную привязку, например к `ObservableCollection` или `BindingList`, то вы можете подписаться на событие изменения коллекция, через которой получите измененные данные, а на основе этого уже шлите в базу запрос.

Comment: [Updating Data Sources with DataAdapters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters?source=recommendations). Вы же написали sql-запрос `select`, вот так же напишите sql-запрос `update`. Или можно сгенерировать его: [Generating Commands with CommandBuilders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/generating-commands-with-commandbuilders).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, хм, а что не так с адо.нет и чем его заменять? ЕФ и другими орм'ками? ну такое, на мой взгляд адо.нет хорошо помогает сориентироваться в sql и в целом в запросах и работе с бд

Comment: @Pekor На вкус и цвет как говорится. Спорить тут я не вижу смысла что лучше, а что нет, просто интересно, почему все новички берут его как некое единственное решение (из-за которого часто страдают). Ну а EF, это знаете, как запросы HTTP отправлять, вы можете сами открыть соединение, состряпать пакет, отправить, то есть, все держится на вас. Или вы можете взять готовые инструменты, например `HttpClient`, который откроет за вас соединение, за вас зашифрует все как надо, отправит, вам лишь надо вызвать метод. Также и EF, настроили и используете так, будто работаете с коллекцией, без запросов.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, да я бы с радостью взял EF, вот только университет другого мнения на этот счёт:)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а как тогда еще изучать sql, в субд или в консоли запросы что ли писать? `просто интересно, почему все новички берут его как некое единственное решение` - моё мнение (так как я сам раньше юзал адо.нет и потом перешел на EF) таково, что адо.нет помогает лучше изучить sql-запросы и работу с базой данных с помощью C#, так сказать посмотреть как оно работает под капотом, а потом уже переходить к linq to sql и EF

Comment: @Pekor Ну, не знаю как вы, а я SQL понял довольно давно очень простым способом - установкой MySQL и первоначальным созданием своей базы вручную, он довольно прост. Все, после этого я никогда больше не использовал SQL запросы, мне достаточно было либо UI элементов, либо вон EF в программировании. Не всем нужно знать, что и как там под капотом, некоторые просто хотят достать из некой базы данные, просто и удобно. Это конечно знание полезное, но знание нынче "вытесняющееся" такими инструментами как EF. Больше полезны тонкости базы, как вот именно она работает, а не как к ней обращаться.